# Linux Traffic Logging

Tags: linux, iptables, router, logging

I'm looking for a good free method of logging IP heading information (src/dest IP with timestamp) passing through a Linux router.

I know I can do this with

`tcpdump -i eth0 > log.txt`

However I'm looking for something a bit more substantial, as this will be running all the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want detailed logging, I suggest ulogd.

Comment: ulogs seems good. I'm guessing that the ULOG target will return back to the FORWARD chain? Also, in your opinion, would it be better to run this on a dedicated box with its NIC in promiscuous mode, given that this will be running 24/7 outputting to a DB?

Comment: Well, that depends on the traffic volume. The ulogd daemon has a  small footprint, so its fine. If you wanna log to mysql, that should probably not run on the router if this is production environment.

Answer (score 2):

iptables can do this natively. just put a `LOG` or `ULOG` target early in your chains.  You'll also have to play with `rsyslogd` to get the iptables logs out of the kernel logging stream and into a file of your choosing.  This necessitates you putting some unique characters in the log text you select with the iptables rules (something like `":FW:"`) so you can tell rsyslogd to filter based on that string and put it in its own file.

Answer (score 1):

I really like using [argus](http://qosient.com/argus/) for this. It is a software package that promiscuously listens on an interface and writes out flow data similar to (net|j)flows. It uses the client/server model, where the server daemon performs the capture and writes the data files, and the client tools are used to read and analyze the data files. The output files are written into a binary format, so some learning curve in the included tools is necessary.

Using a (nearly) default config what follows is an anonymized version of the basic output:

```
StartTime            Proto    SrcAddr  Sport          Dir   DstAddr  Dport       SrcPkts  DstPkts     SrcBytes     DstBytes State  
31 Jan 11 23:20:07   icmp     10.8.23.225             ->    10.28.5.232               1        0           60            0   ECO
31 Jan 11 23:48:07    tcp     10.10.238.252.12200     ->    10.28.5.232.27977         1        0           60            0   REQ
01 Feb 11 01:10:59   icmp      10.15.36.226           ->    10.28.5.232               1        0           60            0   ECO
01 Feb 11 01:11:00   icmp      10.15.36.226           ->    10.28.5.232               1        0           60            0   ECO
01 Feb 11 01:13:45    tcp     10.10.238.252.12200     ->    10.28.5.232.27977         1        0           60            0   REQ
01 Feb 11 01:36:13    udp      10.18.16.98.5060       ->    10.28.5.232.5060          1        0          454            0   INT
01 Feb 11 03:22:34    tcp     10.10.238.252.12200     ->    10.28.5.232.27977         1        0           60            0   REQ
01 Feb 11 04:05:51    tcp     10.10.238.252.12200     ->    10.28.5.232.27977         1        0           60            0   REQ
01 Feb 11 04:48:32    tcp     10.10.238.252.12200     ->    10.28.5.232.27977         1        0           60            0   REQ
```

It is designed to run as a service, however you must figure out the best way to rotate out files depending on your system, storage, and throughput. You should be able to point it at one of your router's interfaces and get all of the information you desire.

As a bonus, tt also comes with a significant number of helper utilities with which you can do fun stuff like traffic graphs, accounting, and other kinds of analysis. See the [NSMWiki](http://nsmwiki.org/Argus) page for some details on exactly the kind of analysis that can be run.

Answer (score 1):

ntop ? If i understand what you want. that'll give you a nice web interface for all the data, and its easy as pie to install.

Answer (score 0):

[Pastmon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pastmon/)? [mrtg](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/)?